# Controls Disappear after implementing fade effect to a carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel

I'm using a normal Bootstrap template where on the main page I have this slider. Since it's a simple one I wanted to add a fade effect to it .. and I did... 
Simply I added this code to my CSS

```
.carousel.fade {
opacity: 1; }

  .carousel.fade .item {
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    left: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .carousel.fade .item:first-child {
        top: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .carousel.fade .item.active {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
        -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
        transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

and then I changed the class of the carousel to carousel-fade. Luckily for me this works. I'm having the fade effect BUT my controls (arrows) for switching the next and previous slides suddenly disappeared. I'm having this confusing for long time and I can't understand how can a simple fade effect make the controls of the slider to disappear. Technically they are there, but somehow they are not visible. Here is my HTML code aswell

```
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel fade">
                    <!-- indicators for the slider -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- images for the slider -->
                    <div id="carousel" class="carousel fade">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider8.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider4.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider5.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider6.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider7.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="img/slider9.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls for the slider-->
                    <a class="left carousel-control"  data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: provide your html code too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this class to your css,

```
.carousel-control { z-index: 2; }
```

It happened because you have given a `z-index:2` to your `.carousel.fade .item.active` class. So the slider image came on top of the controls.

**EDIT:**

You have to change your this part of your html like this in order for the buttons to work

```
<!-- Controls for the slider-->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: it does appear now , but now the control is "unclickable". I cant swtich between the slides.

Comment: It is because you have made a mistake in your markup... Let me update my answer for you

Comment: Check the answer now @dtmnn

Comment: Oh Great ... it works :) I have never tought about this simple way. Thank you very much!